# What is the best way to determine if a users geo-location is from gps or elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, webkit, geolocation

Right now i'm building this feature for webkit and I was wondering the best way to determine if the coors are coming from gps or some wifi/skyhooking business. Should I just test the user agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends why you need to know, but you might want to use `coords.accuracy`. Presumably GPS coords will have a better accuracy than wifi etc. Check out [Diver Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) for a good discussion of geolocation.